# SQL Слияние таблиц

Tags: sql, структуры, join

Есть список товаров, где есть поле `title` и `desc`. И есть другая таблица с переводами: `title`, `desc`, `key`. Где `key`, это — язык пользователя (ru, en и т.д). Как одним запросом выдернуть список всех товаров и склеить его с переводами, если они есть. То есть объединяются товары с общим id. Например, запрос с условием en, для всех товаров, где есть перевод, значением `title` и `desc`поменяются, а в остальных случаях останется из списка товаров. Так же уместны рекомендации об организации другой структуры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select coalesce(t2.title,t1.title) as title, coalesce(t2.desc,t1.desc) as desc
from t1 left join t2 on t1.id=t2.id and t2.key = 'en'
```

[coalesce](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_statement/page2.html)

Comment: Если я дописываю условие WHERE `t2`.`key` = 'en', то вернет только те элементы у которых есть перевод. То есть переводов 5, а товаров 7, например. Вернет 5

Comment: @Fortael нужно дописывать `and t2.key = 'en'` в `join` таблицы, а не в общее условие `WHERE`.

Comment: @VitalyKolyada,это идеально подходит. Единственный нюанс, что доступ к полям можно получить теперь только так: $query[0]['coalesce(lang.title,shop.title)']

Comment: @Fortael думаю это можно вылечить указав `coalesce(t2.title,t1.title) as title , coalesce(t2.desc,t1.desc) as desc` в `select`